# How to add a custom footer to my Magento 2 theme?

Tags: magento2, template, theme, footer

My theme inherits from Blank. I know how to remove the footer links: Contact us, Advanced Search, etc... then I'd like to add a custom footer with 4 columns:

column 1 - Account links
column 2 - general information links
column 3 - Payment logo icons
column 4 - Newsletter sign up form

All elements would be in a footer.phtml template, however I dont know how to add this phtml file to the footer area.
And which folder this file should be located in? I know how to override templates, but the Blank theme does not have a footer.phtml enabled, so there is no a specific path to put my phtml file in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In default.xml from module `Magento\Theme` add this code inside footer referenceContainer

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="block-footer" after="footer_links">
      <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">block_footer_custom</argument>
      </arguments>
</block>
```

Goto backend Content > Blocks > Add new  static block with `identifier` name block_footer_custom with any html code you need. It so easy to editable
Clear cache and re-deploy static. Now you will get your custom block

====**UPDATE**====
Call block inside template

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_footer_custom')->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Which folder should I put the phtml file into?

Comment: You can add your own template. See in xml , inside `block` tag you can add attribute `template` to specific template of block

Comment: why did you choose class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" here? Are there other options too? Or is there a place where i can see all possible classes? Kind of confused about that. thx

Comment: Use cms block because this class you can pass identifier by arguments like you see in layout

Answer (score 2):

The following solution works in Magento 2.1+ including Magento 2.2+. All instructions are based off you being logged into Magento as an admin.

1. Create a CMS block with your links or anything you want to show in the footer:
   `CONTENT > Blocks > Add New Block`
2. Add a new widget to your Magento installation:
   `CONTENT > Widgets > Add Widget`
3. When the New Widget page first loads most options will be hidden you need to change the type to `CMS Static Block` and pick the theme to attach this widget to; you should choose the theme your using for your site.
4. You may have to save the widget at this stage and then just re-open it for editing. Under `Widget Options` select the block you created in step 1.
5. Click `Save and Continue Edit` and now you can finish setting up the new footer. Under the `Layout Updates` section you will need to tell it to `Display on All Pages` and then choose `CMS Footer Links` as the container option.

Comment: i fallowed but its not working for me.

Comment: Worked for me V2.2.7